# Compare bytes from file read with uint value

Tags: c#, byte

I am read the first x bytes from specific file:

```
        uint LIBPCAP_MAGIC = 0xa1b2c3d4;
        uint LIBPCAP_MAGIC_ENDIAN = 0xd4c3b2a1;

        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("file", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            byte[] buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(50);

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length - 4; i++)
            {
                uint currentValue = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, i);
                if (currentValue == LIBPCAP_MAGIC || currentValue == LIBPCAP_MAGIC_ENDIAN)
                    Console.WriteLine("FOUND!!!");
            }
        }
```

After that i have this constant `uint` value:

```
uint LIBPCAP_MAGIC_NUMBER = 0xd4c3b2a1;
```

And i want to make sure if my first x `bytes` (in this example 20 bytes) contains this `uint` value.

So in this example i have this `string hex` but i wonder if this is the best way to read the bytes and convert to `string hex`.
Maybe i need to read the `bytes` and not convert it ?

Comment: `BitConverter.ToUInt32` can do this. You don't need to convert to string hex just use the bytes. uint is only 4 bytes so not sure how you want to compare that to 20 bytes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can i have code example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip the hex conversions completely and just use a sliding conversion, this is assuming that the `VALUE` can be found *anywhere* in the first 20 bytes:

```
public static void Main()
{
    uint VALUE = 0xe3c6a7d1;
    using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("File.bin", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        byte[] buffer = binaryReader.ReadBytes(20);

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length - 4; i++)
        {
            byte[] temp = new byte[4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, i, temp, 0, 4);
            temp = temp.Reverse().ToArray();
            uint currentValue = BitConverter.ToUInt32(temp, 0);
            if (currentValue == VALUE)
                Console.WriteLine("FOUND!!!");
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What is happening is that you read the first 20 bytes right away into a buffer, then use a for-loop to search through the buffer, converting the 4 bytes at the current location (`i`) to a `uint` and comparing it against `VALUE`.

Comment: this never get into the if statement

Comment: Are you sure the first 20 bytes contains that `uint` value for the example file? Is the byte-order reversed in the example file?

Comment: Yes the inside, BTW i edit the uint value that i am search.

Comment: I updated the code and ran it against a test file, I apologize, the endianness is reversed when reading from the file, so the bytes were backwards, it had to be swapped.